# Invalid NSF version while registering a new user by using Lotus Notes Java API

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using Lotus Notes Java API to interact with Lotus Domino Server. I have written an application using remote client API with `NCSO.jar`

I Googled but didn't find anything close to my situation.

Basically, i am trying to register a new user. When i execute my code it throws exception saying `Notes Exception: Notes error: Invalid NSF version`

Can you guys please point me the right direction?

Comment: Just a wild guess: you're registering on a test server, registering a user whose mail file already exists. The file was copied from a production server, and the production server is running a higher version of Domino than the test server. I may be completely wrong, but you've not given enough details here for anything other than a wild guess. In any case, my thought process is that the server itself wouldn't run if files like names.nsr or log.nsf had an invalid version, so we're looking for a file that only registration cares about, and that would likely be the mail file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell much about your configuration, so guessing that you have a database with an old ODS.

In Domino 9 there is a new compact switch "-upgrade". see [Upgrading ODS for databases with old DB class in Domino 9](http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/upgrading-ods-for-databases-with-old-db-class-in-domino-9.htm?opendocument&comments).

You may also have to update you local NOTES.INI: see [CREATE_R85_DATABASES enables ODS 51](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/create_r85_databases)